# Jsoup output - the element printed only one time if it duplicated

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working on   [this link](http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48&pid_tag=103)  to extract some texts inside divs ( prices) , but I have a problem ,if there a duplicated text it would be out printed one time only!.

this is my code

```
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48&pid_tag=103").get();
   System.out.println(doc.select("div").select("div.txt28") );
```

The output **should be** like this

```
<div class="text-black txt28 arial mart-10">
  85 
 <span class="txt16"><b>ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 599
 <span class="txt16"><b> ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 444
 <span class="txt16"><b> ريـال</b></span>
</div>
 ** <div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 388
 <div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 388
```

but the output displayed to me like this ( 388 printed only one time)

```
  <div class="text-black txt28 arial mart-10">
 85 
 <span class="txt16"><b>ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 599
 <span class="txt16"><b> ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 444
 <span class="txt16"><b> ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 388
 <span class="txt16"><b> ريـال</b></span>
</div>
<div class="align-c text-black txt28">
 399
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the response which you get, in this case the doc. I think there is a problem with your input itself or the way in which you are selecting/filtering the doc elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector seems wrong. Try this

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://deals.souq.com/sa-ar/?id_tag=48&pid_tag=103").get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div.txt28") );
```